# Regex: How to remove all characters that are not connected to figure (next to specific characters)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, string

I have a function that returns a result like this: [given output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eIF4.png)

My given string could be compared to this example:

> var string = '    111   1   1\n 1111111 1 \n         11111 11      11'

Ok you see: My string includes some **'1'**, **space** and **new line** characters.

Now I'd like to get as regex result something like this (**remove all red circled chars**) : [result output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugb6u.png) 

 SO the regex should **remove** all **'1'-characters** that are **not connected** to a **big '1'-character row**.

(Sorry, I know it sounds super crazy, but I need exactly this result :p)

EXAMPLE: 

`var string=' 111  1111111111111111 11    1'`

```
var result='1111111111111111'
```

(remove all **'1' / ' '** - groups that are not directly connected to the biggest string between 2 space characters - ['1111111111111111'] )

I just hope you can get what I mean:)

Thanks in advance, jonathan

PS: Textoutput : [pastbin.com](https://pastebin.com/0UQmPr6W)

Comment: In other hand can we say you are going to get longest match of 1s?

Comment: shure i't should give exactly the same result or? @revo

Comment: It's more a XY problem. It returns same output but with a clearer approach: removing vs matching.

Comment: Can you include actual string as text at Question?

Comment: Sure, edited @guest271314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something as simple as `\d{8,}`. This regex will help you match any digit `\d` with a condition that it has 8 digits or more.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bvhMDL/1/

Example

```js
var string = ' 111  1111111111111111 11    1';
var regex = /\d{8,}/g;
var match = regex.exec(string);
document.write(match[0])
```

Here is another example if your string has multiple lines.

```js
var string = `
 111 1  1111111111111111 11    1
 11 1   1\n   11111111111 11    1
 1   1\n 1  1111111111111111111 11    1
 11   1\n   111111111111 11    1
 111  1111111111111111111 11    1
 1 1   1\n   1111111111111111 11    1
 111  1111111111111111111 11    1
 11 \n 111111111111 11    1
`;
var regex = /\d{8,}/g;
var match = regex.exec(string);
while (match != null) {
  document.write(match[0]+'<br>')
  match = regex.exec(string);
}
```

With real data, make sure to use `1{8,}` instead of `\d{8,}` since you have zeros there as an input. Here is an example with real date

```js
var string = `
Array (134)
0 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
1 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
2 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
3 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
4 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
5 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
6 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
7 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
8 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
9 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
10 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
11 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
12 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
13 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
14 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
15 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
16 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
17 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
18 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
19 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
20 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
21 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
22 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
23 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
24 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
25 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
26 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
27 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
28 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
29 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
30 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
31 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
32 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
33 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
34 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
35 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
36 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
37 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
38 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
39 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
40 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
41 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
42 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
43 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
44 "0000000000000000000000000000001100000000000000000001100000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000"
45 "0000000000000000000000000000001110000000000000000000000000000000000000011100000000000000000000000000"
46 "0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000"
47 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
48 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
49 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
50 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
51 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
52 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
53 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
54 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
55 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
56 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
57 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
58 "0000000000000000000000000000000000011100111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
59 "0000000000000000000000000000000000001100111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
60 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
61 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
62 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
63 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000100000000000000000000000000000000"
64 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100001110000000000000000000000000000000"
65 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000100000000000000000000000000000000"
66 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
67 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
68 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
69 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111110000001111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
70 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
71 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
72 "0000000000000000000000000000010000000000111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
73 "0000000000000000000000000000111000000001111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
74 "0000000000000000000000000000010000000001111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
75 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
76 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
77 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
78 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
79 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
80 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
81 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
82 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000"
83 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
84 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011100000000000000000000000000"
85 "0000000000000000000000000001100000000000000000000000000000000000000000011100000000000000000000000000"
86 "0000000000000000000000000001100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
87 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
88 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
89 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
90 "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
`;
var regex = /1{8,}/g;
var match = regex.exec(string);
while (match != null) {
  document.write(match[0]+'<br>')
  match = regex.exec(string);
}
```

Comment: Can you also give me the regex to replace all (currently deleted) '1' chars with spaces? Greetings

Comment: @jobyom My pleasure. I added an additional example with real data for your convenience. As for your question, replacing the currently deleted '1' chars with space is a little bit tricky. You could try something like `(1{8,})|(1{1,4})`. This will help you match the '1' chars that were deleted. Then, you can replace them with space using javascript. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/u0Szwb/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think, one of the way is using \b

```
 '    111   1  '.replace(/(\b1{0,7}\b)|( +)/gi, '')
```

Comment: Would this regex only work if the longest sequence was 8 or more characters in length? I feel the author of the question would need it to be more dynamic