# Find connected components in javascript array? Using BFS or DFS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, regex

I'have an array that looks exactly like this: 
[image: output 0 image]

And I like to find all connected '1'-characters to get as result maybe something like an array that includes the char positions of all connected '1'-characters you can see on this image: [image: output 1 image]

Afterwards I'd just like to just keep the biggest connected array figure (In this case 'E') and delete all other arrays.

I hope you can share some ideas / code snippets, because I'm sooo desperate :p

PS: Textoutput : [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/0UQmPr6W)

```
var arrays='1111000000000000000111','0000111111111000000000',...
```

Greetings -Jonathan

Comment: How is current Question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116223/regex-how-to-remove-all-characters-that-are-not-connected-to-figure-next-to-sp?

Comment: Before I had a string using regex to get a result. In this case I have an array and like to find some kind of figures with BFS or DFS, clear?. -Jonas@guest271314

Comment: Again, the image does not reflect the actual text. Can you include the formatted actual array or text at stacksnippets at Question or linked gist https://gist.github.com or plnkr https://plnkr.co  if the text length is greater than stacksnippets permits? How do you create or get the array? Are you sure the data is an array?

Comment: The data is separated into different arrays that all have the same length (e.g.100). Every array includes 0-chars or 1-chars or both. Like you can see on my pastebin link above. Thanks @guest271314

Comment: The data at pastebin is in string format. How do you create or get the data?